# why get "first/second chance not available" in the core dump

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, dump

I use windbg to debug the crash dump, in the following output from the windbg, you can see that "first/second chance not available", Why the first/second chance not available here? what does this mean?

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(e38.2270): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
```

Answer (score 4):

*[first/second chance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675)* refers to exceptions that can be thrown and the handling mechanism of the debugger that can be utilized.  When debugging an application with a debugger, the debugger get's to see the exceptions *before* the application does, and so get's a *first* chance at handling them.

A *[first chance exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)* is one that is handled by the debuggers *first chance* mechanism for handling exceptions.

The fact that none is available here most likely means that no exceptions were thrown where this error occurred or that no first chance handling mechanisms are available in the debugger to handle any exception that was thrown.

I would put my bets on the fact that this error has no exceptions being thrown because of it, it's just a seg fault.

Comment: `This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it` implies an exception was raised. The seg fault *is* an exception. Do not confuse C++ exceptions with [SEH exceptions](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx).

Comment: @RemusRusanu I would assume that under windows an access violation is a SEH exception that is system generated, right?

Comment: Yes, my question is, since the exception was raised, what does "first/second chance not available" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.dumpanalysis.org/ `(first/second chance not available)` means that information about whether an exception was first-chance or second-chance is missing in a crash dump file. [How to distinguish between 1st and 2nd chances](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2008/01/02/how-to-distinguish-between-1st-and-2nd-chances/)

Demystifying first-chance exceptions (Part [1](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2008/05/22/demystifying-first-chance-exceptions-part-1/)
, [2](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2010/02/04/demystifying-first-chance-exceptions-part-2/)).